# Unsupported image format error though images are all there

Tags: python, pygame

```
folder_dir = "Pieces"

print(os.listdir(folder_dir))

for image in os.listdir(folder_dir):
    img.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(f"Pieces/{image}").convert_alpha(), (dimensions[0]/8, dimensions[1]/8)))
```

I'm trying to load a list of images for my game but it keeps giving me this error:

```
File "/Users/ragesh/Desktop/Coding_Work/ChessAI/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    img.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(f"Pieces/{image}").convert_alpha(), (dimensions[0]/8, dimensions[1]/8)))
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pygame.error: Unsupported image format
```

I have a folder called "Chess AI" with a python script and a folder called "Pieces". The "Pieces" folder has the images I'm trying to access. Images are in a .png format.

When I do img.append(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("Pieces/WK.png").convert_alpha(), (dimensions[0]/8, dimensions[1]/8))) it works but the above code doesn't work.

I've tried tinkering around with the directories and changing the loop but nothing works.
Please help.

Comment: *"Unsupported image format"* means that the image is there, but the format of the image is not supported by your system or the image file is corrupted.

Comment: The images are in a .png format and it works when I custom type the name. It doesn't work in the loop though.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. What gives `print(f"Pieces/{image}")`?

Comment: Put a `print(image)` in the loop, so you can *see what file is causing the problem*.  It's almost certainly going to be something other than an image - perhaps a hidden file of some sort.

Comment: Pieces/WK.png
Pieces/Bk.png
Pieces/.DS_Store
Pieces/WN.png
Pieces/Bn.png
Pieces/WB.png
Pieces/Bb.png
Pieces/Br.png
Pieces/WR.png
Pieces/WP.png
Pieces/Bq.png
Pieces/Bp.png
Pieces/WQ.png

Comment: There is something with a .ds_store extension

Comment: It doesn't show up in the file though, so I'm not sure how to delete it.

Comment: The problem is `Pieces/.DS_Store`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Unsupported image format"* means that the image is there, but the format of the image is not supported by your system or the image file is corrupted. `os.listdir` gives you all files and subdirectories in the folder not just the image files. So you try to load a file that's not an image. You have to test the file extension:

<s>`for image in os.listdir(folder_dir):`</s>

```py
png_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_dir) if f.endswith('.png')]
for image in png_files:
```